# Xamarin forms iOS splash screen with lottie animation before Xamarin App starts

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have implemented the Lottie animation splash screen on android with the new Intent, is there a way to do the same in iOS.

I know LaunchScreen.storyboard is unable to do this, but is there a way to generate a new UIViewController show it on screen with Lottie animation, and while the animation is playing in I will prepare Xamarin App in background task, and when animation ends call LoadApplication(app).

Or is there any other way to start playing Lottie animation first when you launch your app on iOS ?

Setting Lottie animation as the main page in Xamarin Forms is not an option, waiting on Xamarin Forms to start the app will take a few seconds and during that time I wanna show animation, not after.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/splashscreen

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve you cant play animation on the lunch storyboard screen you can only show static images

Comment: ahh, I did not know that. Then this isn't an issue specific to Xamarin Forms? - have you googled `ios splash screen animation`, to see if anyone has a work-around?

Comment: On a high-end iPhone, my client's app comes up in a fraction of a second. (It was Android where Xamarin Forms gave us performance problems.) Please make a **release build** of your app, attach an **iPhone (not emulator)**, download to iPhone. Kill app, then **start from desktop**. About how long does it take before the first screen appears, and on **what model** phone? Do this with a very simple start page - not Shell - just ContentPage with a label - to time the underlying stuff. I can show how to defer loading app's ResourceDictionary, but first would like to know how much time it takes now.

Comment: That is, I'm saying that it is possible to get XForms to a point where it can do something interesting (whether a Lottie animation or anything else), in so little time that it isn't worth the effort of trying to do something in native code before Xamarin is live But need more details about your situation, before giving advice.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yes you are absolutely right, it took like 500 ms to show the app and it's not worth it .. i was doing android version where this is much worse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. iOS Launch screen can't animate. If startup time is an issue, and you want to show some animation, would need to write some "native code" (Xamarin.IOS is fine) that does an animation, while you have a background task do Xamarin Forms Init and load App ResourceDictionary. Details TBD, if someone demonstrates that they actually have a serious iOS load-time problem with Xamarin Forms.
2. OP (Original Poster) tested the time on iPhone, and concluded that it was fast enough to not be worth doing an animation to make that time more interesting. (On typical Android devices the startup time was longer.)